# Convert data frame from character to numeric

Tags: r, text, character

I have the following data frame with one column, which is currently stored as a character column:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98iSj.png)

I am trying to separate the text, but it seems like the separate() function doesn't work on character columns.

I tried to covert the columns, using the following codes. Neither of them works for me.

First try:

```
Overview_10_K_filings_df$Overview_10_K_filings <- as.numeric(as.character(Overview_10_K_filings_df$Overview_10_K_filings))
```

This creates the error message: "Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion"

Second try:

```
Overview_10_K_filings_df[1] <- apply(Overview_10_K_filings_df[1], 2,
                                     function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

Can you help me to transform the column? Or is there any other way that I can separate the content?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Could you explain how do you want to separate the text? Which characters define the separation between columns?

Comment: Yes, of course. So right now this is the name 

"QTR4/20151229_10-K_edgar_data_1230058_0000892626-15-000373.txt" 
  
and I would like to covert it to: 


QTR4  | 20151229 | 10-K |edgar | data | 1230058 | 0000892626-15-000373 | txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a **DF** out of the string and using `str_replace` in 3 steps.
Maybe not the most concise way of achieving the goal. The three steps are kept in the **DF** for informative reasons how the replacing goes.

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
t <- "QTR4/20151229_10-K_edgar_data_1230058_0000892626-15-000373.txt"
t |> as.data.frame() |> 
mutate(new1=stringr::str_replace(t, '/', ' | ')) |> 
  mutate(new2 = stringr::str_replace_all(new1, '_', ' | ')) |> 
  mutate(new3 = stringr::str_replace(new2, '.txt', ' | txt')) |> 
  select(new3) |> as.character()
#> [1] "QTR4 | 20151229 | 10-K | edgar | data | 1230058 | 0000892626-15-000373 | txt"
```

**Better:**
Or you do it this way:

```
b <- "_|/|\\."
stringr::str_replace_all(t, b, ' | ')
# [1] "QTR4 | 20151229 | 10-K | edgar | data | 1230058 | 0000892626-15-000373 | txt"
```

Comment: Hi @MarBlo, thanks for your answer. The code works for me, but unfortunately I can't store the output in a new data frame. When I try it, all the characters are linked back together. So basically, for my code, the seperation only shows up in the console and not the actual dataframe. Do you have any idea how I could solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @`Li4991` If you take the first approach above, there is a **DF** build which contains the three intermediate steps in each column. Just leave the `select` out. For the second approach you can assign the result `new <- stringr::str_replace_all(t, b, ' | ')` to the **DF** like `DF$new <- new`